# Unable to connect to the remote REST service from the IIS-hosted application

Tags: c#, rest, iis, soap, https

I have a SOAP web service that is hosted in IIS on my machine. This SOAP service has several methods which may interact with the remote REST service that uses Basic authentication.

I use the following code to make a POST request to the REST service from my SOAP service:

```
HttpClient serviceClient;
serviceClient = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myremoterestservice.com:9981/callme/")};
serviceClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    $"myuser:mypassword")
            )
        );

string postXml = "my request XML";
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = serviceClient.PostAsync("methodname", new StringContent(postXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
// I need to get the result synchronously
using (var response = task.Result) // exception "A Task was cancelled" thrown here
{
    using (var content = response.Content)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Everything works with the different remote REST service that uses HTTP. But when I try to call the same method for the REST service that uses HTTPS, this code throws an exception with the message "A task was cancelled" at the line `using (var response = task.Result)`

But this doesn't work only when I'm calling that code via my SOAP web service - it fails even to establish a connection with the remote REST service. When I'm calling the same code from my unit-tests, it works.

I think the issue may be somewhere in the IIS settings or in the web.config file of my SOAP web service, but I don't have an idea where exactly.

UPDATE:
I noticed that TLS 1.2 is used when I'm running this request from my unit-tests in visual studio. When I'm running it from my IIS-hosted SOAP web service, TLS 1.0 is used.

Comment: What if you use `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`?

Comment: I tried it too, but nothing's changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to compare request that I made using the Visual Studio with the request that was made by the SOAP web-service, and I noticed that there was a difference in a TLS version: TLS 1.2 was used when I run the request using Visual Studio, and the TLS 1.0 was used by the web service. I found that the issue was in the web.config file of my SOAP web service. The following setting was specified in the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

TLS 1.2 was supported by default only since .NET 4.6. So, when I changed httpRuntime targetFramework to 4.7, everything started to work. It seems that the remote REST service was configured to not allow TLS 1.0 to make a handshake.